# nginx does not output all add_headers

Tags: nginx

i have set up the following in my nginx site config:

```
server {
    ...

    add_header Referrer-Policy "no-referrer" always;
    add_header Strict-Transport-Security "max-age=31536000; includeSubdomains" always;
    add_header X-Frame-Options "SAMEORIGIN" always;
    add_header X-Content-Type-Options "nosniff" always;
    add_header X-Xss-Protection "1; mode=block" always;

    ...
}
```

but if i have a look at my side i only see two of five headders

```
HTTP/2 200
server: nginx
date: Fri, 06 Apr 2018 08:58:49 GMT
content-type: text/html; charset=utf-8
content-length: 114649
vary: Accept-Encoding
x-frame-options: SAMEORIGIN
x-content-type-options: nosniff
last-modified: Fri, 06 Apr 2018 08:58:49 GMT
expires: Thu, 19 Nov 1981 08:52:00 GMT
cache-control: private, no-cache, max-age=0
set-cookie: __Secure-anzah_csrf=Fmv0S0-WCZwP5fy5; path=/; secure
set-cookie: __Secure-anzah_session=IxXVlychxqE2F4lXUwW79gKwrxiTlhuQ; path=/; secure; HttpOnly
cache-control: private, no-cache, max-age=0
```

does anyone know what could be the cause?

Comment: Do you have other `add_header` directives within an inner block?

Comment: only a `add_header Cache-Control 'private, no-cache, max-age=0';` for html/php files

Comment: Have you looked at the response using `curl -i`?

Comment: @RichardSmith the second code part in the first post is from curl -i
have edit the first post

Comment: I don't understand why the `curl` results are all lower case. When I try this, I get all of the headers and in the same case as the `add_header` statement. You could try changing a value of one of the headers that do work - to see if you are looking at the correct source and that your changes are being committed.

Comment: your right @RichardSmith it looks like the header does not come from the virtual host file for this domain, but atm i dont know where they come from

Comment: i have searched all config files but only in the virtual hosts file i have the add_header tags